# How to adjust number of rows for each asp.net multiline textbox in a table using jQuery?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have a Table with multiple rows. These rows contain an asp.net multirow textbox

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Invoice 1</td>
        <td><asp:TextBox ID="invoiceDesc" runat="server" Rows="1" TextMode="MultiLine"></asp:TextBox></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Invoice 2</td>
        <td><asp:TextBox ID="invoiceDesc" runat="server" Rows="1" TextMode="MultiLine"></asp:TextBox></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Invoice 3</td>
        <td><asp:TextBox ID="invoiceDesc" runat="server" Rows="1" TextMode="MultiLine"></asp:TextBox></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

The table is rendered using an asp.net gridview control. I'm trying to adjust each textbox number of rows depending on the content loaded.

So far I've tried adding the code below to $(document).ready :

```
var text = $("#<%=invoiceDesc.ClientID%>").val();   
var lines = text.split(/\r|\r\n|\n/);
var count = lines.length;
$('#<%=invoiceDesc.ClientID%>').attr('rows', count);
```

But the jQuery Code above doesn't work.

Comment: What does the rendered HTML look like?  Does the jQuery code run at all?  It certainly can adjust the `rows` attribute of a `textarea`: http://jsfiddle.net/zN2Yq/

Comment: The textbox has a multiline content loaded everytime the page is loaded. I didn't post the whole rendered html because it's too big. Anyway, I have to count each lines in the text box and then adjust the "Rows" attribute depending on how many lines are there in that textbox in that row.

Comment: How about the *relevant* rendered HTML?  You're trying to debug an issue in client-side code, so examining the client-side code would be a good place to start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace the javascript code given below and pass your textarea id instead of test that i have used as sample.

```
        var count = 20;  //set the cols attribute of the textarea here i have set it to 20 just for an example which is by default for HTML textarea 
        var lineCount = ($('#test').val().length / count); 
        var lineBreaksCount = ($('#test').val().split('\r\n')); 
        alert(Math.round(lineCount)+1);
```

I hope this will solve your problem :)